# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined variable: user

Tags: php, laravel

Undefined variable: user
Values are not updating..

ProfilesController.php file....

```
public function edit(User $user)
{

    return view('profiles.edit',compact('user'));
}

 public function update()
{

  $data= request()->validate([
    'title' =>'required',
    'description'=>'required',
    'url'=>'url',
    'image'=>'',
]);
  $user->profile->update($data);

  return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");

}
```

web.php file......

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.*

Comment: Which is correct, The `$user` variable is never defined in the `update()` function.

Answer (score 3):

You are not accepting the `User` within the `update` method for route model binding, like you are on the other endpoints. Try changing your update method from

```php
public function update()
```

to

```php
public function update(User $user)
```

Comment: public function update(User $user)
-After doing this. I gote that error-SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list'

Comment: Then whatever model the profile relationship represents it does not have the `image` column in the database table. Check your migrations.

Comment: After migration, I get this error-Trying to get property 'title' of non-object